# how to get a part of file path?

Tags: python

for example I have string:

```
test = "/var/tmp/test.log"
```

I want to get a path of this file.

Comment: No idea what you want specifically, so... http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

Comment: What exactly do you want? You have the path right there, so I do not understand the problem. Can you give an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`os.path.dirname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.dirname('/var/tmp/test.log')
'/var/tmp'
```

Comment: Also check out os.path.basename, and os.path.split.

Answer (score 0):

```
 >>> import os
 >>> os.path.dirname("/var/tmp/test.log")
 '/var/tmp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Which part are you interested in? The [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module has a lot of useful functions. If that fails, a `.split("/")` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get absolute path, try this

C:>python
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
>>> import os.path
>>> test = '.'
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(test))
'C:\\'
```